# How do I assign a value to a specific row and column in a pandas database?

Tags: python, pandas

I have an integer:

`num = 1`

,and a database table `points`:

```
   X   Y
0
1
2
3
```

How would I go about placing `num` into column `X` and field `3` using pandas?

I have searched around and found `points.ix[]`, which selects a specific row but using this I get an error message:

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'ix'`

Apart from this I can't find anything else.

Comment: `df.loc[3,'X'] = 1`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Exactly what I was looking for, it works.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Please repeat any tutorial on PANDAS to learn how to access individual cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.ix` deprecated since version 0.20.0

You can use `df.loc[3, 'X']` for the same result.

Answer (score 0):

you can also try,
df.iat[3,0]

Thanks